# CircleCI can't run "claudia update"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, circleci, claudiajs

Im running CircleCI and Claudia.js to deploy my node.js code to AWS Lambda.

Here is my package.json (scripts part):

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "claudia create --handler lambda.handler --deploy-proxy-api --region eu-central-1",
    "update": "claudia update",
    "generate-proxy": "claudia generate-serverless-express-proxy --express-module server",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec"
  },
```

When i'm running:

```
npm run update
```

in terminal, I can update just fine. But when i'm running this in CircleCI it fails.

Here is my CircleCI config file (.circleci/config.yml):

```
version: 1
jobs:
  build:
    machine:
      node:
        version: 6.11
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: install
          command: npm install
      - run:
          name: test
          command: npm run test
  build:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: generate-proxy
          command: npm run generate-proxy
      - run:
          name: update
          command: npm run update
```

The error in CircleCI is:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm run update

> xxx@0.1.0 update /home/circleci/project
> claudia update

loading Lambda config
loading Lambda config   lambda.getFunctionConfiguration FunctionName=xxx
loading Lambda config   lambda.setupRequestListeners
{ CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:864:34)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  retryable: false,
  time: 2017-06-21T08:02:53.894Z,
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     retryable: false,
     time: 2017-06-21T08:02:53.894Z,
     code: 'CredentialsError' } }
```

I have a file called .aws/credentials that contains:

```
[claudia]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxx
```

EDIT:

## changed config.yml to match that of CircleCI 2.0

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/emailservice
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:4.8.2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: update-npm
          command: 'sudo npm install -g npm@latest'
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: install
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: test
          command: npm run test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-results.xml
          prefix: tests
      - store_artifacts:
          path: coverage
          prefix: coverage
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results.xml
      - run:
          name: deploy_update
          command: npm run update
```

Everything works except for credentials as in before.

## logfile from CircleCI:

```
loading Lambda config
loading Lambda config   lambda.getFunctionConfiguration FunctionName=emailService
loading Lambda config   lambda.setupRequestListeners
{ [CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: Thu Jun 22 2017 08:11:27 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  retryable: true,
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     time: Thu Jun 22 2017 08:11:27 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     retryable: true,
     originalError: 
      { message: 'Connection timed out after 1000ms',
        code: 'TimeoutError',
        time: Thu Jun 22 2017 08:11:27 GMT+0000 (UTC),
        retryable: true } } }
npm info lifecycle xxx_email_service@0.2.0~update: Failed to exec update script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxx_email_service@0.2.0 update: `claudia update`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxx_email_service@0.2.0 update script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2017-06-22T08_11_27_089Z-debug.log
Exited with code 1
```

Do I have to add credentials in AWS somewhere? I can still use the terminal to deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to a way how CircleCI is handling users.

I would suggest using environment variables to store AWS access key and secret.

You need to add following environment variables:

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` - with your access key as a value
`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` - with your secret key as a value

More info on setting up the keys via environment variables in AWS:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html

More info about env variables in Circle CI:
https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go!

Comment: That seems to work, however I have a new problem. Will keep searching for that answer. Thansk!

Comment: What's the problem? Feel free to ask, I am from Claudia team. Also, for Claudia related questions you should check our gitter, ie. post stackoverflow link there and someone will jump in and try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing the creds in the file you mentioned in your repository? Firstly, you probably shouldn't, it's a security no-no. If you are, it needs to be at `~/.aws/credentials`. Based on your current config, your entire repo is located in the build at `~/emailservice`. You'd need to create the `aws` directory and then move the creds with `mv`. Something like:

```
mkdir ~/.aws
mv ~/emailservice/my-creds-file ~/.aws/credenials
```

Alternatively, I would suggest not having a file in your repo and use [private environment variables](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-for-all-commands-without-adding-them-to-git). In this scenario, you'd set the variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in CircleCI's web UI. The AWS CLI will then see and use these credentials when running.

The AWS CLI auth methods can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
CircleCI Developer Evangelist

---

Original Response:

I'm not 100% sure exactly why the error you're getting is happening, but it looks like you have a bigger problem. That config file doesn't look to be correct at all. Concepts and config syntax from both CircleCI 1.0 and 2.0 are being mixed in an incompatible way. I'd check the config syntax at https://circleci.com/docs/ and choose which version of CircleCI you'd like to use.

Afterward, either on here or [CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com) we can attempt to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will have a check vs the docs and get back to you if I don't solve it.
Should we take the discussion here if further problems arise? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my config file and everything works except the original problem which is still there. The credentials error.

I'll edit my question with my new config file.